# Hudson/jenkins: disable the failed build

Tags: hudson, jenkins

What is the preferred way to disable the periodical build when it has failed? Quick search showed that there is a Prerequisite build step plugin, but that fails the build, and I need the build to be completely disabled until manual intervention.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, I think I managed to find a solution.

- Retry Failed Builds plugin didn't work because it could not override the default project schedule, so the failed project got built again and again.
- Naginator plugin didn't work because the delay is not configurable.
- Prerequisite build step plugin is not suitable.

The solution is to install the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin), which is run under the Jenkins JVM and exposes the Jenkins instance publically. So it is possible to programmatically disable the current build directly in the Project configuration:

```
if (manager.build.result.isWorseThan(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)) {
  manager.build.project.disabled = true
}
```

Comment: @Vladimir Sinenko i tried this.nothing in groovy postbuild script is getting executed.even println. what might be the problem

Comment: Can you provide more context for the answer? Where would this code be placed in the pipeline script? In a header? In a stage? In a step?

Answer (score 3):

There is a button "Disable project" on the project status page. I simulate button click by HTTP POST message with data "Submit=\"Disable Project\"" like this

```
wget  --post-data  "Submit=\"Disable Project\"" ${JOB_URL}disable
```

right from the bash script which runs the build (project). The whole code can look like this

```
set +e
#  Run test/build
#  ....
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
  wget  --post-data  "Submit=\"Disable Project\"" ${JOB_URL}disable
#  Or you can use following to disable one job from another
#  wget  --post-data  "Submit=\"Disable Project\"" http://<Server>/job/$JOB_NAME/disable
  exit -1
fi
```

This is a rather old question, so I guess there was no Disable/Enable button in Jenkins GUI than. If Jenkins is protected by a password you will need to make wget to login first, store cookies in some file and in the second file add the cookie.