# How to check disabled jobs with Jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-api

I am using Jenkins to run tests on my servers.

So I created a job for each server and I run the test on the job, and I would like to know with simple bash script if my specific job is disabled/enabled?

I can ssh to Jenkins server and I want to run that script from there how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `http://<Your Jenkins>/api` and `http://<Your Jenkins>/api/xml`:

```xml
<hudson>
  ...
  <job>
    <name>...your job name...</name>
    ...
    <color>disabled</color>
  </job>
  ...
```

For a job's description see `http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<Your job's name>/api` and `http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<Your job's name>/api/xml`.

Comment: is it possible to grab subprojects of specific project i am looking at?

Comment: @מורןזהובה By "subprojects" you mean _downstream_ projects? If yes, see `<downstreamProject>` in `.../<your job's name>/api/xml`.

Answer (score 4):

Check the project status from this string

```
curl http://$JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/api/json | python -mjson.tool
```

It will dump the job data in json format. then grep for string "buildable":

this will give you whether project is wither either enabled or disabled.

```
"buildable": true, --> Project enabled
"buildable": false,  --> Project Disabled
```

Then do whatever you want.

Comment: You can also add `?tree=buildable` to your request URL so that Jenkins will return only the `buildable` attribute - then you can leave out the pipe to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Put your jenkins server URL in browser and Put /api/xml infront of your URL.

Example:

```
https://xyz.jenkins.com/view/all/api/xml
```

Or

to get result in json just put json instead of xml in above mentioned URL

```
https://xyz.jenkins.com/view/all/api/json
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add to the existing answer.
To get more precise result you can add xpath filter

```
http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<job name>/api/xml?xpath=//disabled
```

or

```
http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<job name>/api/xml?xpath=//buildable
```

In response you will get only one line:

```
<disabled>true</disabled>
```

Filtering also works with json api output:

```
http://<Your Jenkins>/job/<job name>/api/json?tree=disabled&pretty=true
```

Output:

```
{
  "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
  "disabled" : true
}
```