# How to disable a job if it failed three or more times?

Tags: jenkins

I want to disable a job if it fails three or more times. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6270048/1184842) to disable it immediately. But I want to wait three times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the previous result from `build.previousBuild`. For example:

```
def failingForAtLeast(build, n) {
    def failed = build.result.isWorseThan(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS );
    if( n <= 1 ) {
        return failed;
    } else if ( failed && build.previousBuild != null) {
        return failingForAtLeast(build.previousBuild, n-1);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if ( failingForAtLeast(manager.build, 3) ) {
  manager.build.project.disabled = true
}
```

Comment: Looks very good, I test it and accept if it is working.

Comment: With `def failed = build.result.isWorseOrEqualTo(hudson.model.Result.FAILURE);` it's working as I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need the Groovy PostBuild plugin